# How Do I Set An Option in GetFiles to Include SubDirectories

Tags: vb.net

I'm using the code below to try and list all the files in a directory and all its sub-directories. I'm getting the ones in the "root" directory but not the others. Investigation has told me there's a search option I have to set for the GetFiles but I can't find what that option is or how to set it. I'd appreciate any help.

```
        For Each foundFile As String In My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles(strArchRoot)
            ListBox1.Items.Add(foundFile)
        Next
```

Comment: `My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles(strArchRoot, FileIO.SearchOption.SearchAllSubDirectories, "*.*")`

Comment: Just don't set your "root" direction to high or you'll get a bunch of access exceptions and it'll fail.

Comment: Thank you Sean. This is what I was looking for. In the environment in which my application will run, file access won't be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Add to Sean's comment.  Here is [more info](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory?view=netframework-4.8) on SYSTEM.IO.DIRECTORY:

```
   System.IO.Directory.GetFiles("\\Path", "*.*", IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories)
```

***Note:** the difference between the parameter orders when using My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles vs System.IO.Directory.GetFiles.*

Answer (score 0):

An issue is that both of the methods above will be apparent if their are privilege problems.  This approach will localize that.

To use the functions

```
    ListBox1.Items.AddRange((From o As Object In GetFiles(strArchRoot)
                                Select o).ToArray)
```

The functions

```
Private Function GetFiles(strArchRoot As String) As List(Of String)
    Dim rv As New List(Of String)
    Try
        rv.AddRange(GetSubFiles(strArchRoot))
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
    Return rv
End Function

Private Function GetSubFiles(folder As String) As List(Of String)
    Dim rv As New List(Of String)
    Try
        rv.AddRange(System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(folder, "*.*", IO.SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly))
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
    Dim ds() As String
    Try
        ds = System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(folder)
        For Each p As String In ds
            rv.AddRange(GetSubFiles(p))
        Next

    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
    Return rv
End Function
```

Comment: That's a good point; but, eating the exception seems like treating the symptom and not the problem.  Gives you a false sense that you have a full listing of files when you might not.